# Example of a not good kernel

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

**Background** Given a sequence ${K_n}$ of functions on region $T$. Then ${K_n}$ is a good kernel if:

(1) $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} K_{n}(x)dx = 1$ $\forall n \in N$

(2) $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |K_{n}(x)|dx = O(1)$

(3) If $\delta \in (0,\pi)$, $\int_{\delta \leq |x|\leq \pi} |K_{n}(x)|\ dx \rightarrow 0$  as $\ n\rightarrow \infty$

**Problem** I am trying to come up with an example of a NOT good kernel which will satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$ but fails to satisfy $(3)$. But I only tried to mimic the construction of Dirichlet Kernel to see if I can find such not good kernel, but unfortunately nothing is successful. Can anyone please help on this problem?

Comment: Take $K_n \equiv 1$.

Comment: Great example! I feel so dumb when I see your answer though:P Many thanks, PhoemueX!

Comment: By the way, I computed $(3)$ and got $2(\pi-\delta)$, and this does not approach $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ only when we fixed $\delta$ beforehand. Is that the correct interpretation for $(3)$?

Comment: Yes, the interpretation of (3) is that for each fixed $\delta>0$, the convergence $\int_{\delta\leq|x|\leq\pi} |K_n(x)| \, dx \to 0$ has to hold. The dependence on $\delta$ can be arbitrary, as long as the condition above is fulfilled.

Comment: (3) above is not true because of fixing $\delta$. Can you please explain what you meant by "the dependence on $\delta$ can be arbitrary?"

Comment: Jut forget abou that part :) I just wanted to emphasise that you have to **fix** an arbitrary $\delta$ beforehand. I meant that it does not matter (for example) if $\int_{\delta \dots}\dots =1$ for e.g. $\delta = 1/n$, because $\delta$ **must not** depend on $n$.